# How can i use a Gridview efficiently in asp.net by using only the keyboard?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

i need to use my gridview by using only the keyboard.My clients prefer keyboard rather than using mouse.How can i use my gridview like that?What all events should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Are you permitted to use Javascript libraries (with or without Ajax)?
If your answer is **yes** then I suggest you don't reinvent the wheel on something this complex and go for something like [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com), even though all you'll need is a `GridPanel`. It has all keyboard support in it, you can use paging, sorting, filtering etc. And it also provides a very nice look and feel (even though you'll have to change it to your customer's needs).

If you won't use Ajax (XHR) calls to the server, you can still load your data into your page into JavascriptBlocks and use it on the client side to provide data for the `GridPanel`.

But if you are still at the very beginning of development and can still change bits of technologies used I suggest you take embrace ExtJS. Your client will love it, and you won't have to develop something that's been developed long ago.

BTW: I don't work for Ext llc even though you may thought so. I just had a routine client that used keyboard extensively.

Comment: Just my 0.02: If you use ExtJS and don't release ur code under open source, then u would need to purchase a commerical license

Comment: Yes,i am permitted to use Javascript libraries

Comment: Commercial licences are cheap especially if you're creating a commercial product.

Comment: @Nandu: great! I suggest you follow the link in my answer and see some examples. You'll simply love the capabilities. Though it does take a short learning curve. But a seasoned developer should grasp ExtJS' concept in about a week.

Comment: From which site do i get this?